# How do I stop Visual Studio Code from opening a browser window when I start debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I debug a .Net Core application in Visual Studio Code by pressing F5 it opens a browser window. How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Deleting the `serverReadyAction` section in my `launch.json` solved the problem.